# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } even do everything right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I don't understand this code should make an editable table but I have a but on a } and I see nothing. Everything match.
the code is:
http://www.dollarannonce.com/Cmaisonneuve/Client-serveur/TP2/Ajax-POO/index.php

The index.php code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">    </script> 
<script>
        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            console.log(column+" : "+id);
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
            $.ajax({            
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                     $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                 }      
           }); 
        }

        </script>
<script>
var titre11 = 'titre';
$.ajax({
     url: 'jsonTable2.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
     /*data: {
        json: jsonData
    },*/
  success: function (response) {

        //alert('toto');
        //alert(response);
        //console.log(response);
        //response = $.parseJSON(response);
        var trHTML = '';
        //alert('allooo');
        $.each(response.livres, function (id,item) {
            trHTML += '<tr><td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"titre",'+item.id+')" onClick="showEdit(this);">' + item.titre + '</td>';
            trHTML += '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"auteur",item.id)" onClick="showEdit(this);">' + item.auteur + '</td>';
            trHTML += '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"annee",item.id)" onClick="showEdit(this);">' + item.annee + '</td>';
            trHTML += 'td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"isbn",item.id)" onClick="showEdit(this);">' + item.isbn + '</td>';
            trHTML += '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"editeur",item.id)" onClick="showEdit(this);">' + item.editeur + '</td>';
            trHTML += '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"titre",item.id)" onClick="showEdit(this);">' + item.evaluation + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="records_table" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Titre</th>
        <th>Auteur</th>
        <th>Année</th>
        <th>Isbn</th>
        <th>Éditeur</th>
        <th>Évaluation</th>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why the code doesn't work. Every { as is } there is no extra.

Comment: The linked page renders fine for me in Chrome.  What application is giving you this error?

Answer (score 1):

the script that writes the table is all messed up
`trHTML += 'td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"isbn",item.id)" onClick="showEdit(this);">'`
it will create a *onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"* and a bunch of junk on a tag, not to mention you're missing the pulp fiction bracket in this line in particular. *pulp fiction wtf?* it's the "< >". fix this script and then your onblur should start to work (or crash properly at least).